# Cocoa: How to handle invalid utf-8 bytes in a webpage

Tags: cocoa, url, unicode, encoding, nsstring

I am trying to get the contents of a webpage using `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. The problem is that the webpage has invaild utf-8 bytes so the method returns nil. How would I would I handle the invaild utf-8 bytes?.

Things I have tried.

- Tried using every encoding in `NSString.h` and `CFStringEncodingExt.h`
- Using NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, then removing the invalid bytes then doing

  `[NSString stringWithCString:[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
- `stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` which results in the Japanese Unicode characters being gibberish.

Webpage I am using `http://vgmdb.net/album/32234`

Using `iconv`  the invalid char seem to `EF BF BD` in hex

```
`iconv -c -f UTF8 -t UTF8 32234.html`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this using iconv api which discards the invalid unicode characters.

I used `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` to download the url. I converted it to `NSData` run `cleanUTF8:data` on it then read the data using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. This was the only way I could find to get the japanese and other unicode characters to display properly.

```
- (NSData *)cleanUTF8:(NSData *)data {
// Make sure its utf-8
iconv_t ic= iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-8");
// Remove invaild characters
int one = 1;
iconvctl(ic, ICONV_SET_DISCARD_ILSEQ, &one);

size_t inBytes, outBytes;
inBytes = outBytes = data.length;
char *inbuf  = (char*)data.bytes;
char *outbuf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * data.length);
char *outptr = outbuf;

if (iconv(ic, &inbuf, &inBytes, &outptr, &outBytes) == (size_t) - 1) {
    assert(false);
    return nil;
}

NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:outbuf length:data.length - outBytes];
iconv_close(ic);
free(outbuf);
return result;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is the best encoding to use for the web page? Perhaps you should instead use:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

This method determines the best encoding to use for you and returns it in `enc`.

Comment: I tried this and it results in the the Japanese Unicode characters appearing as gibberish

Comment: What encoding does it tell you was best to use for that page? (Returned in the `enc`)

Comment: nsisolatin1stringencoding which mess up the japanese characters.